# Frequent STS/Eclipse Oxygen crash after upgrading my System RAM from 4GB to 12GB ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, 64-bit, eclipse, crash

My Ubuntu 16.04 system was continuously freezing when I was using STS. I ugraded my ram to 12GB thinking that it may resolve the issue. But after upgrading that, My STS started crashing frequently. I have tried to switch to eclipse IDE. But getting the same issue. I have searched about it and have tried different ways like adding:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla,
--launcher.GTK_version 2,
```

Or increasing `-Xms512m`, `-Xmx2G`. I have also tried

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

Earlier but nothing is working. I have checked my new RAM configuration and it is same as that of already installed, I dont think that my RAM is faulty. It's been a week and i am no where close to resolve it.

My `eclispe.ini` configuration details are in [this link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JwRTDGWRbF/), due to the length of it.

Comment: Please take your time and format it. Also remove unneeded information.

Comment: Are you sure your RAM is not faulty? Did you replace the existing RAM or just add more on top? Assuming the latter, likely your old RAM is perhaps bad. Try removing it and seeing if things improve. You might want to run the memtest from grub as well.

Comment: You had errors with the old 4 GB Ram. I would remove it and just use the new 8 GB Ram only.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your response. As suggested by you , i ram memtest86 tool. It ran for around 4 hours. But there was no error reported by tool and all cases ran successfully. It means that both old and new RAM is fine and there must be something else which is causing this behavior. Please help